# How do I make my Racket-designed language run scripts from external files?

Tags: racket

I've got a custom language I'm designing in Racket, let's call it `waffle`.

Let's say I have

```lisp
(define (printstr . input)
   (if (string? (car input)) 
       (write (string-join input ""))
       (write input)))

; ... a whole bunch of other definitions

(command-line
 #:multi
 [("-v" "--verbose")    "more verbose"      (set! loglevel (add1 loglevel))]
 [("-q" "--quiet")      "be quiet"          (set! loglevel 0)]
 #:once-any
 [("-i" "--in-place")   "edit in-place"     (set! mode 'in-place)]
 [("-c" "--create-new") "create a new file" (set! mode 'new)]
 [("-n" "--dry-run")    "do nothing"        (set! mode #f)]
 #:once-each
 [("-d" "--directory") dir "work in a given directory" (set! root dir)]
 #:help-labels "operations to perform:"
 #:multi
 [("+l" "++line") "add a line"    (set! ops `(,@ops "add"))]
 [("-l" "--line") "delete a line" (set! ops `(,@ops "delete"))]
 [("-e" "--edit") "edit a line"   (set! ops `(,@ops "edit"))]
 #:args (file)
 (define in (open-input-file file))

 ; This is probably where I'm going wrong with how my language REPL evaluates files passed to it.
 (eval (file->list file) ns))
```

Then I create an executable from DrRacket using 'Racket [menu] -> Create Executable ... -> [Type] Launcher'. Name is e.g. `waffle-test`.

I've got a file written in my waffle language, `hello.waffle`:

```
(printstr "Hello!")
```

I expect this to print 'Hello!' on the command line and then exit without errors. But I get a strange error I don't understand, and I get my prompt back without a newline.

```
$ ./waffle-test hello.waffle 
application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: #<void>
  arguments...: [none]
  context...:
   eval-one-top12
   "/home/connie/Desktop/racket-ffgardfghf/waffle": [running body]
   temp37_0
   for-loop
   run-module-instance!125
   perform-require!78
"Hello!" $
```

I know you're not supposed to use `eval` but I can't find out how to make my language executable read and run files I pass to it. What is the best approach to doing this?

Comment: Have you tried `read-syntax` instead of `file->list` ? 
https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Reading.html?q=read-syntax#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._read-syntax%29%29

Comment: Also, can you show us what `(file->list file)` alone gives as result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By fixing a few bugs in my code I managed to solve my problem!

I changed

```
(eval (file->list file) ns))
```

to

```
(define program (cons 'begin (file->list file)))

(eval program ns))
```

I also changed the 'printstr' function from

```
 (define (printstr . input)
   (if (string? (car input)) 
       (write (string-join input ""))
       (write input)))
```

to

```
 (define (printstr input)
   (displayln input))
```

Answer (score 2):

Just with this simple test I figured out a couple of things:

```
#!racket
(file->list "test.waffle")
```

With `test.waffle` as:

```
(waffle me)
(waffle it)
```

The repl printed:

```
((waffle me)
 (waffle it))
```

However that is not valid code, even if `waffle` is a valid procedure. You need it to look like this:

```
(begin
  (waffle me)
  (waffle it))
```

Now you can do this by require your language to have it, but you can also just `cons` a `begin` to the resulting structure and eval will evaluate each top level form one by one in order.

You will run into problems with using `eval`. You'll know that soon enough. The correct way to make an interpreter is by creating your own `eval` that implements your languages syntax and takes en environment with primitives. It has an interface to use the host, but not regardless. With `eval` `waffle` programs has access to all internals and you're not really creating an interpreter since you just expose Racket.

I remember someone did the same with Ruby and had a web page and someone just tried to type in a command that deleted all the files on the system and the web service went away.